# SAS external file relative paths for Enterprise Guide

Tags: import, path, sas, relative-path

I have a SVN structure for my SAS project.

```
\trunk
  \my sas code
  ... sas programs.sas
  \my external resources
  ... my_spreadsheet.xls

  my_sas_eg.egp
```

I have enabled relative path in Enterprise Guide and things are working well with the SVN.
I'm now trying to integrate the my_spreadsheet.xls file

When doing my proc import, I want to use the relative path to my xls, so I do

```
datafile=".\resources\gmax_pricing_xref_tables.xls"
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't get redirect to where the EG folder is, but to:

```
C:\Windows\system32\
```

I am basing my assumptions out of:
http://support.sas.com/kb/12/002.html

I am doing things wrong obviously, how do I get the path of where the EG file sits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should be stored in a macro variable `&_CLIENTPROJECTPATH`.  To confirm this is what you want, try executing

```
%put &_CLIENTPROJECTPATH.
```

and see if that matches what you expect (it should include the .egp file, which you'd need to strip out).

More detail is available in Chris Hemedinger's blog post [How to assign a library to the same path as your SAS Enterprise Guide project](http://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2011/07/11/how-to-assign-a-library-to-the-same-path-as-your-sas-enterprise-guide-project/).